# PDO execute: Array to String conversion

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting an Array to String conversion error

errorCode() --> 00000

errorInfo() --> Array

```
public function getUserInfoByMail( $userEmail )
{
    if (is_mail($userEmail))
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer INNER JOIN addresses ON customer.customerid = addresses.customerid WHERE standard='1' AND deleted='0' AND email=:email");
        if ($sql->execute(array(':email' => $userEmail))) 
             return $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        else 
             throw new Exception("There was a DB-Error!");
    }
    //....
}
```

Why am I am getting an Array to String conversion error?

Comment: so perhaps `$userEmail` is an array?

Comment: Read the php manual for errorInfo. It's an array with SQLState error, errorcode and error message. http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a DB-Error!' in C:\...\customer.dao.php:107 Stack trace: #0 C:\...\login.php(107): CustomerDAO->getUserInfoByMail('test@test.com') #1 {main} thrown in C:\...\customer.dao.php on line 107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->execute() expects you to send it an array with each element representing each ? in the query.\
```

The main cause of the problem is by only sending it with 2 elements so it use the array as second...Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049317/pdo-execute-array-to-string-conversion-error)

Answer (score 0):

error code `00000` means, you have no error. Just try to convert the `errorCode` to `int` and it will evaluate to false